# Execution of Expression Trees

Tags: .net, dynamic-language-runtime

To work with DLR, the dynamic language should be converted to expression trees. What happens when i execute the application that i developed using the dynamic language.

For example a hello world application. What happens at runtime to execute the expression tree code. How actually the communication of expression tree to OS work ?

Answer (score 2):

Expression trees are just another way to build a sequence of IL instructions.  The IL from the expression trees will be JIT compiled to native hardware instructions just like IL from C# or other source language compiled to IL.

Comment: AFAIK, the expression tree is **not** compiled for the DLR...? Indeed, given the dynamic nature of such objects, this seems like it **simply can't work**.

Comment: You mean to say, whatever i write in my dynamic language will be converted into IL and JIT compiled at runtime ??

Comment: My understanding is that DLR, LINQ, C# and others use the expression tree API as an easier way to specify executable logic than emitting IL opcodes. See the Microsoft documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)  To use expression trees, you construct a series of nodes, then call Expression.Compile(). That's where IL is emitted and where the expression becomes JIT'able and executable. If expression trees were only interpreted data graphs, the performance cost of C# lambda expressions would be horrific. DLR probably uses expression trees to rewrite code on the fly.

Comment: If DLR does everything at runtime, the running time for these dynamic languages will be slower than c# running time ( since in c# while execution, the existing IL is JIT compiled whereas in dynamic language like IronRuby, IronPython creation of IL & JIT compilation occurs at runtime ). Makes Sense ??

Comment: @HukmChand I would argue that dynamic languages use expression trees to emit IL code to use DLR routines to get/set dynamic properties or methods on an object instance. DLR provides an indirection for accessing object members which enables changing the object type/metadata on the fly. If the dynamic language code is IL, and it uses DLR which is IL (or native), it seems to me the whole thing can be JIT compiled to native code on the fly. DLR may take more time for member access compared to C#, but most program logic (loops, numerics, ifs, etc) would be the same JIT compiled IL. IMO.

Answer (score 0):

My **understanding**, which may be limited (I'm not a DLR expert) is that in the case of using an Expression, the expression tree is walked for nodes such as `MemberExpression`, and the names of each member / method / etc are used to talk to each object's provider. This *probably* means using the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface, passing in the expression. Walking the expression for key nodes is very similar to technologies such as LINQ providers, except in many ways simpler (because there is a more direct mapping - it doesn't have to be re-phrased in a foreign language such as SQL).

The implementation of the dynamic object is determined **by that dynamic object**, but *may* then mean looking up values from an internal dictionary of values (for example, `ExpandoObject`), or could be *anything at all* (for example, some ad-hoc subclass of `DynamicObject`, or a from-first-principals `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` implementation).

In the case that a type **does not implement** `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` (i.e. a non-dynamic object floating in a dynamic world) then typically reflection will be used as a fallback, caching the mechanism to do this (possible since reflection is not dynamic, and cannot be monkey-patched etc).